# django model find where count on filter is minimum

Tags: django, django-models

Hi there I have A model which I save ip in four column:

```
class IPAbstract(Audit):
    first = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(254)])
    second = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(254)])
    third = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(254)])
    forth = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(254)])

   

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

which All my ips are start with 10.0.0.0,20.0.0.0,30.0.0.0,40.0.0.0
I want find which my ip range has minimum rows,
i can do this:

```
IPAbstract.objects.filter(first=10).count()
IPAbstract.objects.filter(first=20).count()
IPAbstract.objects.filter(first=30).count()
IPAbstract.objects.filter(first=40).count()
```

and compare them to each other to find which has minimum rows.
I want see if there is there another way to find my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from django.db.models import Count

IPAbstract.objects.values('first').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('number')
```

This will generate a `QuerySet` of dictionaries that look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'first': 30, 'count': 5 },
    { 'first': 10, 'count': 9 },
    { 'first': 40, 'count': 11 },
    { 'first': 20, 'count': 20 },
]>
```

values for `first` that do not appear in the `IPAbstract` records will of course not be listed.

You can thus obtain the dictionary with the smallest value for `'count'` with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

IPAbstract.objects.values('first').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('first', 'number').first()
```

Comment: thanks
can I use first?
`reseller_client_model.PeerConfig.objects.values('first').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
Out[5]: <QuerySet [{'first': 10, 'count': 11}, {'first': 20, 'count': 7}, {'first': 30, 'count': 7}, {'first': 40, 'count': 7}]>
reseller_client_model.PeerConfig.objects.values('first').annotate(count=Count('pk')).first()
Out[6]: {'first': 10, 'count': 1}`

it changed count from 11 to 1

Comment: @SaebMolaee: what if you include `'first'` in the `.order_by`?

Comment: `reseller_client_model.PeerConfig.objects.values('first').annotate(count=Count('pk')).order_by('-count').first()
Out[10]: {'first': 10, 'count': 11}`

did the trick, thanks